# Nightwatch not navigating to url

Tags: javascript, cucumber, nightwatch.js

I have the following code and whats happening is that once the promise is resolved the browser doesn't navigate to the url it just stay on the default page defined on the nightwatch.conf.js. So the test fails.

```
Given(/^I make a post request and retreive the Id i got the page + id$/, () => {
      //I make the post request 
      var transactionIdPromise = utils.getTransactionId(1);

      return transactionIdPromise.getBody('utf8').then(JSON.parse).done(function (result) {
          var id = result.transaction_id;
          var url = "https://mywebpage.com:8443/" + id;
          client.url(url)
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to properly chain the promises. As `client.url` is an asynchronous operation it is returning a promise. You have to return that to make Cucumber.js runner await the whole promise chain to be resolved before going to next step.

```
Given(/^I make a post request and retreive the Id i got the page + id$/, () => {
      //I make the post request 
      var transactionIdPromise = utils.getTransactionId(1);

      return transactionIdPromise.getBody('utf8').then(JSON.parse).then((result) => {
          var id = result.transaction_id;
          var url = "https://mywebpage.com:8443/" + id;
          return client.url(url)
      });
    });
```

Comment: Hi mucsi96 I tried chaining the promises as you said, but it's not working the promise isn't being resolved, so it moves towards the next step.

Comment: Please submit an issue on GitHub with a minimal example to reproduce the issue. As base you can use https://github.com/mucsi96/nightwatch-cucumber-example

Answer (score 0):

My solution was changing the done for a then on the promise, even though I´'m still unsure on why this worked.